# $timeout wrapping $http.post return undefined instead of promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to submit a form that require that the user email is not duplicated, but I want to make an small animation before the POST request. In the `$scope.process` function I'm getting:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`.

That's happening because `$scope.process` is returning before the `$http.post` is complete, but how can I make process() return the promise instead of undefined?

So, this is what I have so far:

```
//The submit form function
$scope.submitForm = function () {

  $('.btn').attr('disable');

  if ($scope.form.$valid) {

    $scope.process($scope.account)
    .catch(function (err) {

      if (err.code === 'duplicate') {
        // handle error
      }

    });

    return false;
  }
};

//This is the one in charge to send the request
$scope.process = function(body) {

  // Timeout before http post to wait for animation
  $timeout(function() {

    return $http.post(postUrl, body).then(function (response) {
      // This return a promise if I remove the $timeout
      var nextPage = response.data;
    }).catch(function (err) {
      throw err;
    });
  }, 300);

  // Return undefined due to $timeout
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`, because you weren't returning promise from `process` function at all.
Do return `$timeout` promise from `process` function & apply `.then` & `.catch` over `$timeout` promise object.

By returning `$timeout` service the inner `$http.post` will return a data, so that will make proper chaining mechanism.

**Code**

```
$scope.process = function(body) {
  // returned promise from here
  return $timeout(function() {
    //returned $http promise from here.
    return $http.post(postUrl, body).then(function (response) {
      // This return a promise if I remove the $timeout
      nextPage = response.data;
      return nextPage; //return data from here will return data from promise.
    }).catch(function (err) {
      throw err;
    });
  }, 300);
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm, didn't know $timeout also return promise, thanks!

Comment: @TomSarduy glad to know that.. Thanks :-)